# Direct Mapped, Cache Transactions

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I have attached the problem below

Consider a 512-KByte cache with 64-word cachelines (a cacheline is also known as a cache block, each word is 4-Bytes). This cache uses write-back scheme, and the address is 32 bits
wide.

[image]

Let's try to start doing the first row. To find the Cachline index, I would have to know the number of cachelines in the cache. I don't know that. The problem doesn't provide any information about the cache that is being used. It's going to be a Miss since at the beginning the cache is empty. It wasn't modified because the request is to read. For the tag, I would have to know what's the bit size of the address , but in this case it's in hex. What's data?. what is caused replace? what is write-back to Memory?. It would be nice if someone can do the first two rows for me and go through every step in this process. I would do the other ones. I would like the first two rows to be done because there are two different types of request, read and write. I need orientation. It would be good as well if someone can point out the resources to understand this question.

Thanks!!!

I have updated the thread

In previous computations, I got that cache offset is 8 bits, cache index is 11 bits and the tag is 13 bits. I converted 0x128 to binary and got 0b100101000. This implies that the cacheline index is 1. The requested address is 0x28 and the tag is 0x0, however; I still can't understand what data, caused replace and write-back to memoery means.

Comment: what is the data column? and is it a replace in the cache or in memory?

Comment: I did what you said and got all tags and indexes different. There is clearly something wrong. I think that there is a replace if the indexes and tags are the same.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @tHEMathNoob yes indeed you are correct the conflict arises when the index bits are same. The index bits determine where in the cache the block goes.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Sitting down with you and walking you through exercise problems is not what this platform works well for, and it's probably something that shouldn't have to happen in the first place. Revisit your course material and then try again!

Comment: Community votes, please: unclear?

Comment: @TheMathNoob The data column specifies the data stored at a given physical address in the memory. The physical address is determined by the TAG.

Comment: @Raphael hello Raphael, do you know if there is a web-site in which I can get the tutoring that I want?

Comment: @Shubham Singh rawat  How does M[0x100] relate to its row?

Comment: @TheMathNoob M[0x100] gives us the physical address , then we find the tag of the cache if they both match it means the entry in the cache is valid and we don't need a memory access. In other words cache Hit.

Comment: @Shubham Singh rawat so M[0x100] is in the cache and it equals some physical address that maps some data in memory?

Comment: @TheMathNoob  M[0x100] represents the data present in the physical memory at address 0x100 . Whether or not this data is present in the cache can be checked by matching TAG against this physical address.

Comment: @TheMathNoob No, sorry. You can try if somebody in [chat] is willing to talk with you. Other than that, real-life teachers are your best bet.